# Android drawer and back button in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a situation where a fragment starts an activity when I click on the navigation drawer item.

```
public class CalculateFareFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CalculateFareActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return null;
    }
```

In the activity, when I press the back button, the screen on device flashes and the same activity is shown again. Pressing the back button the second time takes me to the default screen of the app.

Is there a way to overcome this behaviour so that I don't need to press the back button twice?

EDIT : After the suggestion from @spurdow, I managed to addToBackStack(null)

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I still don't see any change in the behaviour. Is there anything else that is missing?

Comment: have u tried adding null to backstack?

Comment: No, I will try it. I have no idea how to do it though.

Comment: when you create a transaction in `FragmentManager` after `beginTransaction` and `add` you have the ability to add it to back stack or null

Comment: Why do you need to create a fragment just to start another activity? Does `CalculateFareFragment` serves other purposes?

Comment: Ok. I will admit I was being lazy. But being lazy led to this situation. I can probably fix the code and change the activity to a fragment. I thought calling the activity from the fragment would be quicker:(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage back button pressed you have to use onBackPressed() class to manage it:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) { drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); } else { super.onBackPressed(); } }
```

and calling an activity within a fragment is normal way to switch between views of them so if you want to manage Navigation Drawer items selection there is a class implemented as below:
example,

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // Handle navigation view item clicks here. int id = item.getItemId(); if (id == R.id.nav_photos) { // Handle the camera action //setContentView(R.layout.myaccount); } else if (id == R.id.nav_myaccount) { setContentView(R.layout.activity_myaccount2); // } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) { UserLocalStore loginuser = new UserLocalStore(this); loginuser.clearUserData(); finish(); startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)); } DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); return true; }
```